# trailing return type in template class (contradiction between GNU and Microsoft compilers)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

The following code compiles on msvc v120 (preview compiler)

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
    int f() const { return 0; }
    auto g() -> decltype(f()) const { return f(); }
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.8.1 complains with the message

> cannot call member function 'int X::f() const without object

Changing `g` to

```
auto g() -> decltype(this->f()) const { return f(); }
```

solves the issue with gcc but now msvc outputs

> C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member
>   functions

Any idea what am I doing wrong in either case?

Comment: Automatically-deduced return types in C++14 solves this problem.

Comment: My intuition suggests that both should be valid. Then again, this _is_ C++ we're talking about...

Comment: Note that there's no reason to use the trailing return type in the above.

Comment: @BillyONeal true. I'm sure there are many cases where a trailing return type is needed like a template is involved with `f`

Comment: @a.lasram: To my understanding, that's why they were added to the language. Though I'd wager `declval` alleviates the need for most of those cases.

Comment: @BillyONeal Indeed `declval` can simplify expressions (sometimes it's a necessity). Also, it turns out to be helpful in overcoming some compiler bugs

Answer (score 2):

First off another data point: clang compiles both the original code and the modified version. I guess, that doesn't really help you much, though. From my intuitive understanding, the code should be correct but intuition can be tricky and I suspect it will take quite a while browsing the standard to tell you that both gcc and MSVC++ are wrong and it won't help you much either.

You might want to try the following work-around, though:

```
auto g() -> decltype(std::declval<X const>().f()) const { return f(); }
```

`std::declval<>()` is declared in `<utility>`.